# Sling logging configuration in Equinox

Tags: java, osgi, logback, equinox, sling

I am trying to use Apache Sling logging in an Equinox project. It is working fine, but I can't make Sling to use my config file. I am using a standard logback configuration xml, which should work according to the [Sling documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/logging.html#logback-integration). But no matter where I put the configuration file Sling just doesn't use it.

My logback configuration is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} *%level* [%thread] %logger %message%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Which locations have you tried to put your logback config file so far?

Comment: @Val I tried putting the config file in `/src/main/resources` which should put it on the classpath and in the root of the project. Neither worked.

Comment: Did you check if the file was at all copied in your deliverable?

Comment: @Val Yes it is copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I managed to get Sling to use my config file is to pass the location of the configuration file as a VM argument like this: `-Dorg.apache.sling.commons.log.configurationFile=/path/to/logbackconfigfile`, where the path is the full path of configuration file location. Unfortunately I haven't managed to get it to work with a relative path.